# Multiple variables por json y ajax con Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, json

les explico lo que he intentado hacer, tengo creado 2 select dependientes, uno se llama **tipo de persona** (Persona Natural y Persona Jurídica) y el otro **empresa**, al seleccionar el tipo de persona, el siguiente select (empresa) cargará los datos que corresponde. Hasta ahi estoy bien. Luego cuando selecciono a una empresa necesito que me cargue datos de la tabla empresa, el detalle está que al mismo tiempo me debe de cargar datos de otra tabla en la que esta el ID de la empresa, en este caso, giro de negocio.

```
   $('#empresa').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var empresa_id = e.target.value;
        //alert(empresa_id);
        $.get('select_empresa?empresa_id=' + empresa_id,function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#empresa_nombre').empty();
          $('#empresa_ruc').empty();
          $('#empresa_mail').empty();
          $('#empresa_tel').empty();
          $('#empresa_dir').empty();
          $('#empresa_giro').empty();
          document.getElementById('infoempresa').style.display = 'block';

          $.each(data, function(datos_empresa, empObj){
            $('#empresa_nombre').val(empObj.companyname_cny);
            $('#empresa_ruc').val(empObj.ruc_cny);
            $('#empresa_mail').val(empObj.email_cny);
            $('#empresa_dir').val(empObj.address_cny);
            $('#empresa_tel').val(empObj.phone_cny);
            //$('#empresa_giro').val("Giro de Negocio"); 
          })

        });
      });
```

En este Script mando a cargar los datos al formulario que contiene los datos de la empresa, el problema es con el campo **Giro de Negocio**

```
function datos_empresa(Request $request)
{
  $empresa_id = Input::get('empresa_id');
  $empresa = Empresa::where('id','=',$empresa_id)->get();

  $giro = negocio::where('empresa_id','=',$empresa_id)->get();
  //dd($giro);

  return Response::json(['empresa'=>$empresa, 'giro'=>$giro]);
}
```

Este es mi función del controlador para cargar los datos, el detalle es que no me muestra nada.

Comment: Que es lo que no te muestra nada?

Comment: No muestra los datos, el display no funciona y no aparecen los datos de la empresa que quiero mostrar. No se si estoy bien en la vista, talves no los estoy llamando de forma correcta en la funcion de la vista

Comment: Que te aparece cuando haces `console.log(data)`  Tambien puedes probar `console.log(datos_empresa)` en tu each loop

Comment: `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/dgj/select_empresa?empresa_id=14 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
w.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ vw_solicitudes_crear:527
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
ListPicker._handleMouseUp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haria de esta forma

```
$("#campoSelect").select2({
                placeholder: "Selecciona una opción",
                language: "es",
                width: '100%',
                ajax: {
                    url: "{{ route('controlador.busqueda') }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            q: params.term,
                            parametro1: variable,
                            parametro2: $('#input').val(),
                            parametro3: document.querySelector('#check' + ':checked').value
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: data
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                templateResult: locationResultTemplater,
                templateSelection: locationSelectionTemplater
            });
```

Aqui el formato de busqueda

```
function locationResultTemplater(data) {
            if (data.text !== undefined) {
                return data.text
            }
            return 'Campo: ' + data.nombre;
        }
```

Y por ultimo el de seleccionado

```
function locationSelectionTemplater(data) {
    if (data.text !== "") {
        return data.text
    }
    return data.nombre;
}
```

Y el controlador

```
            Route::get('busqueda', 'Controller@busqueda')->name('controlador.busqueda');

    public function pieza()
    {
        $q       = trim(e(Input::get('q')));
        $p1 = trim(e(Input::get('parametro1')));
        $p2 = trim(e(Input::get('parametro2')));
        $p3 = trim(e(Input::get('parametro3')));

        $results = Modelo::where('nombre', 'LIKE',
            '%' . $q . '%')
->where('p1', $p1)
->where('p2', $p2)
->where('p3', $p3)
->take(100)->get();

        return Response::json($results);
    }
```